# The ng-repeat directive does not display anything

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code

Html

```
<div ng-controller="moveController as vm">
<div ng-repeat="move in vm.moves">
    Move of the Week are <br />
    {{move}}
</div>
```

JS

```
function getMovesForCurrentWeek() {
       service.get("Move", "List").then(function (data) {
           vm.moves = data;
   });
}
```

vm.moves has the data something like this = ["4","9","27","4","1","28","9"]

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the vm.moves has duplicate values 4 and 9 two times,so mapping is not possible, you need to track this by $index.

try this one

```
<div ng-controller="moveController as vm">
<div ng-repeat="move in vm.moves track by $index">
    Move of the Week are <br />
    {{move}}
</div>
```

helpful link

http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/Tutorial/Angular/angular-conditional-binding

example of track by $index.
http://learnit.visrosoftware.com/try/1LXjq60x

Answer (score 0):

You can use Track by :
See link https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes